# How to reduce the amount of logging for `zookeeper`?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I set up a three-node `kafka` and `zookeeper` cluster more than half a year ago and I am using the `zookeeper` server that came with [the `kafka` package](http://apache.communilink.net/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz). As it turns out, the default configuration results in too much log information being gathered from `zookeeper` (2GB from each node so far).

How can I turn the log level down, and is it OK for me to delete old logs from `zookeeper` abruptly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zookeeper` uses `log4j v1.2` for its logging infrastructure, as you can read [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_logging). You should edit your `log4j.properties` file to set your logging level higher (so it'll only log "more important" events).

You should be able to delete old logs without any issue. Just make sure they're not being read or written to by other programs (including `zookeeper`) first.

It may be easier to just set a task to periodically prune old logs, though, that way you don't lose the granularity provided by the default configuration in case something goes wrong.

Comment: thank you for the reply mate, some further questions, I cannot seem to find any zookeeper specific properties in log4j.properties so which setting should i modify? is that file only used by zookeeper? I never modified that file so it was left as is before. I thought it was used by both zookeeper and kafka...

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. If multiple programs were using that log4j.properties file, you would see context selection of some kind (so you'd spot it right away).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to:

1. Use rolling log so that old logs are deleted automatically
2. Log only issues. This is a configuration in log4j. I've seen instances where it is set to INFO and logs grow substantially.

For instructions on configuring log4j:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html